# Best tool to generate STL (3-D geometry file) algorithmically?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, modeling, cad

I have a simple project in mind that would take a long list of triplets as input (coordinates describing a path in 3 dimensions), and generates an STL file as output. ([STL is a file format that describes 3-D surface geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) for use in CAD and 3-D printing applications.)

I'm a scientist, not a developer, and I'm capable with Python, so I can handle parsing an input text file if needed. What I am looking for is a command line utility, library, or simple programming language that can automate a few simple CAD tasks (e.g. extrude a cross section along a path) to create a true 3-D surface for STL output.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with abamert that this question is off topic, but let me point out that the STL file format isn't difficult if you have a closed triangular mesh.  Since you're conversant with Python you should have no problem outputting to it.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using [**Blender**](http://www.blender.org/)?

It has a [Python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_8/), and can also be used in headless mode (without a GUI) by using [`blender --python script.py`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_8/info_overview.html#script-loading).

It also has an [STL import/export plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/STL) (make sure to enable it in `Preferences -> Addons` if you decide to try it). I'd also suggest to look at its [source code](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons.git/blob/HEAD:/io_mesh_stl/stl_utils.py) if you decide to roll your own.

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but [FreeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/) also looks very promising (includes a Python API, not sure if you can use it without the GUI though). Edit: [You apparently can](http://www.cardanco.com/blog/starting-with-freecad-python.html).